# Which lines should be removed from buildToolsVersion" from build.gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

For the first time I'm trying to use `Android Studio` (3). Probably I'm asking a silly question, but I didn't find any exact answer for my level of knowledge in internet.

I'm trying to modify an android project, and it's more than one hour `Android Studio` is just updating and syncing `gradle`. After all these, it shows such a warning:

```
Warning:The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (25.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (26.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.1.
Android SDK Build Tools 26.0.2 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
```

And here is the build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.brommko.android.universalwebview"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 14
        versionName "3.4"
        manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId          : "${applicationId}",
                                onesignal_app_id               : "c0fbadc6-4013-4613-b00b-566eab144d3c",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "4122760152"]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.+@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1"
    compile 'com.github.quentin7b:android-location-tracker:3.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'
    compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
    compile 'com.github.hotchemi:android-rate:1.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Please keep in mind that I'm really a newbie in Android Studio.
Thanks for your kind attention in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove

```
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
```

which is inside `android {} block`

Answer (score 1):

Delete the "buildToolsVersion ...." line entirely.  That way, Gradle will always just automatically use the correct default version of the build tools that works with the current version of Gradle.